# How to make a Table from Imported data?

Tags: import, list-manipulation

I have imported into *Mathematica* notebook data from TXT file. I would like to make it as a `Table` afterwards, so I can do some calculations. 
I wrote:

I wrote:

```
dat = Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"]
```

It gives out:

```
1   7
2   7
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   2
8   3
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  2
```

If I write:

```
dat = Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"];
fabri = Table[{dat[[i, 1]], dat[[i, 2]]}, {i, 600}]
```

It gives me out ( and does it 3 times):

```
Part::partd: "Part specification" 1 7
2   7
3   2
4   2
5   2
6   3
7   2
8   3
9   2
10  2
11  3
12  2
```

Same thing If I write:

```
dat = Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"];
fabri = Table[{dat[[i, 1]], {i, 1, Length[dat]}]
```

If I write:

```
dat = Import["PirmaisPikis.txt"]; 
fabri = Table[{dat[[i, 1]], dat[[i,2]]}, {i, 1, Length[dat]}]
```

It gives me out nothing {}
What is the problem?

(You can import with `Import["https://pastebin.com/raw/w9ys8Rfd"]`.)

Comment: Without access to PirmaisPikis.txt it is difficult to say. Can you show a small example of the `dat` after importing or share the text file?

Comment: We need to see the all of the curly brackets. Edit and add to the question, not the comment

Comment: You may also put the text file in a dropbox or pastebin for downloading.

Comment: Post the output of `dat[[1;;5]]` if your data is too large. You can try `fabri = dat[[All,1;;2]]`.

Comment: `dat2=ImportString[dat, "Table"] `?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that Mathematica defaultly imports the file as a single string, **not** a table. You have to import the table form the imported string:

```
dat = ImportString[Import["pirmaispikis.txt"], 
   "Table"];
```

or import the file as a table by `Import["pirmaispikis.txt","Table"]`

gives the table you want and

```
fabri=dat;
```